# Almacenar valores enteros y decimales en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Tengo una tabla y en ella tengo un campo definido para guardar valores numéricos (enteros y decimales),

En un inicio ese campo lo tenía declarado de la siguiente forma:

```
cantidad DOUBLE NOT NULL
```

Con esa declaración me almacenaba valores enteros sin decimales y a los decimales les quitaba el último valor pero siempre que fuera un 0, por ejemplo el valor `0.850` lo guardaba como `0.85`.

Investigando encontré que el campo debe ser declarado como tipo **DECIMAL** pero con 2 parámetros:

```
DECIMAL(M, D)
```

- **M** : Número de dígitos que puede soportar el campo
- **D** : Número de dígitos que se toma de `M` como decimales

Entonces ahora el campo lo de clare de la siguiente forma:

```
cantidad DECIMAL(7, 3) NOT NULL
```

Pero a los valores enteros les agrega 3 decimales ejemplo el valor `3` lo guarda como `3.000`, y si guardo un valor con 2 decimales les agrega un 0, ejemplo para el valor `0.45` lo guarda como `0.450`.

Y necesito que si es un valor entero lo almacene como entero es decir sin decimales, si es un valor con 1 o 2 decimales los guarde con sus decimales correspondientes y si es un valor con 3 decimales que lo guarde con los 3 decimales pero que no elimine el 0 siempre que este sea el último valor por que después al imprimir reportes podría haber confusión entre valores decimales por ejemplo: `0.85` y `0.850`.

Como podría solucionar esto??

Comment: *por que después al imprimir reportes podría haber confusión entre valores decimales por ejemplo: 0.85 y 0.850*. Es un falso problema realmente. El dato es del tipo que hayas declarado la columna (decimal en este caso). Sí en un reporte quieres quitar o poner los ceros, debes especificarlo en el formato, sea desde la misma consulta SQL, sea al crear el reporte en el lenguaje de programación que sea. Te aconsejo que no traslades a la base de datos problemas de formato, porque es algo contextual. En otro caso puedes necesitar otro formato por ejemplo.

Comment: Concuerdo con @A.Cedano , mientras tengas tus datos bien estructurados ya del lado de la programacion te encargar de quitarle y ponerle los decimales que quieras. Por ejemplo, para tu reporte puedes redondear cuando quieras los enteros y si los necesitas con decimales lo tomas tal cual lo tienes registrado.

Comment: @A.Cedano entonces por ejemplo, en la BD quiero guardar los valores 0.45 y 0.450, y por el formato que tengo en el campo(en este caso DECIMAL) ambos valores se guardarían con 3 decimales, ejmplo 0.450. Ahora me dices que a esos valores les de formato con el lenguaje de programación que este usando, pero entonces como le hago para indicarle al programa que uno valor es con 2 decimales y el otro con 3??

Comment: Lo que debes entender es que `0.45`, `0.450`, `0.450000000` son la misma cosa. Si necesitas decimales de hasta 3 valores después del punto entonces declara el dato como lo has hecho y luego en el programa define la lógica de lo que necesitas ese contexto, sea la que sea, quitar los ceros de la tercera posición por ejemplo o lo que sea. Es algo que afecta a la representación de los datos, que puede variar en cualquier momento, por eso sería un error querer resolver eso en el diseño de los datos. No sé si me explico.